# RSyntaxtextarea, adding a variable to JavaScriptParser

Tags: java, swing

I'm using **RSyntaxtextarea** to write JavaScript code in my swing app, and get autosuggestions with the **JavaScriptLanguageSupport**.

I'm blocked with this problem:

I want to add this variable to the parser:

```
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  id       : 5566,
};
```

So on my **textPane** I can write: **"person."** and get **firstName,lasName and id** as autosugestions, just like this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8K9Z.png)

**My textPane:**

```
RSyntaxTextArea expTextArea = new RSyntaxTextArea(1, 20);
expTextArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVASCRIPT);
        RTextScrollPane sp1 = new RTextScrollPane(expTextArea);

JavaScriptLanguageSupport languageSupport = new JavaScriptLanguageSupport();
        JavaScriptParser javaParser = new JavaScriptParser(languageSupport, expTextArea);

languageSupport.install(expTextArea);
```

I have tried to call `javaParser.setVariablesAndFunctions` but I'm not able to understand how this method works:

```
JavaScriptVariableDeclaration subject = new JavaScriptVariableDeclaration("s",1,null new CodeBlock(1));

VariableResolver vr = new VariableResolver();
vr.addLocalVariable(subject);

javaParser.setVariablesAndFunctions(vr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do here is implement a custom auto-complete.

Unfortunately, there are quite a few methods to implement in CompletionProvider. The way might be to hack [DefaultCompletionProvider](https://github.com/bobbylight/AutoComplete/blob/master/AutoComplete/src/main/java/org/fife/ui/autocomplete/DefaultCompletionProvider.java) to return custom completions (parsing the text left of the caret yourself, that part is not that hard).

You can directly create an AutoComplete object from your custom completion provider afterwards.

I might experiment with these things myself, but not sure when I'll have time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I expected to solve this problem using the RSTALanguageSupport library, but the other library is ok too.